# Canonical form of PDE, elliptic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$(1+x^2)\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+(1+y^2)\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}+x\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$$

$D=B^2-4AC=0-4*(1+x^2)*1/2*(1+y^2)$

$D<0 \implies \text{elliptic}$ $PDE$

What to do next? 
How to lead to canonical form?

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+x^2)\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+(1+y^2)\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}+x\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$$can be written as
$$(1+x^2)u_{xx}+(1+y^2)u_{yy}+xu_x+yu_y=0\tag1$$
Comparing equation $(1)$ with $$P(x,y)u_{xx}+Q(x,y)u_{xy}+R(x,y)u_{yy}+f(x,y,u,u_x,u_y)=0$$we have $~~P(x,y)=(1+x^2)~,~~~Q(x,y)=0~,~~~R(x,y)=(1+y^2)$

Now $~~Q^2-4PQ=-4(1+x^2)(1+y^2)\lt 0~~,~~~\forall ~x,y$

So the given PDE is of **elliptic** type.

Consider $~P\lambda^2+Q\lambda+R=0\implies (1+x^2)\lambda^2+(1+y^2)=0\implies \lambda=\pm~i~\sqrt{\dfrac{1+y^2}{1+x^2}}~$.

Let $~~\lambda_1=i~\sqrt{\dfrac{1+y^2}{1+x^2}}~$ and $~\lambda_2=-i~\sqrt{\dfrac{1+y^2}{1+x^2}}~$.

Solution of the auxiliary equations 
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}+\lambda_1=0\qquad \text{and}\qquad \dfrac{dy}{dx}+\lambda_2=0$$
$$\implies \dfrac{dy}{dx}+i~\sqrt{\dfrac{1+y^2}{1+x^2}}=0\qquad \text{and}\qquad \dfrac{dy}{dx}-i~\sqrt{\dfrac{1+y^2}{1+x^2}}=0$$
Integrating,
$$\int\dfrac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}+i\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=0\qquad \text{and}\qquad\int\dfrac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}-i\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=0$$
$$\implies \sinh^{-1}y+i\sinh^{-1}x=C_1 \qquad \text{and}\qquad \sinh^{-1}y-i\sinh^{-1}x=C_2$$where $~C_1,~C_2~$are constants.

Let $~~f_1(x,y)=\sinh^{-1}y+i\sinh^{-1}x~~$ and $~~~f_2(x,y)=\sinh^{-1}y-i\sinh^{-1}x~$

Consider the transformation

$\xi=\text{Real part of $~f_1$}=\sinh^{-1}y$

$\eta=\text{Imaginary part of $~f_1$}=\sinh^{-1}x$

Now using chain rule we have the following

$u_x=u_{\xi}\cdot\xi_x+u_\eta\cdot\eta_x=u_{\xi}\cdot 0+u_\eta\cdot\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\dfrac{u_\eta}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

$u_y=u_{\xi}\cdot\xi_y+u_\eta\cdot\eta_y=u_{\xi}\cdot \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}+u_\eta\cdot 0=\dfrac{u_\xi}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$

$u_{xx}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}u_x=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(u_{\xi}\cdot\xi_x+u_\eta\cdot\eta_x)$

$~~~~~~=u_{\xi\xi}\cdot\xi^2_x+u_{\xi}\cdot\xi_{xx}+2u_{\xi\eta}\cdot\xi_x\cdot\eta_x+u_\eta\cdot\eta_{xx}+u_{\eta\eta}\cdot\eta^2_x$

$~~~~~~=u_{\xi\xi}\cdot 0+u_{\xi}\cdot 0+2u_{\xi\eta}\cdot 0-u_\eta\cdot\dfrac{x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}}+u_{\eta\eta}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$

$~~~~~~=\dfrac{u_{\eta\eta}}{1+x^2}-\dfrac{x~u_\eta}{\left(1+x^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}}$

$u_{yy}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}u_y=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}(u_{\xi}\cdot\xi_y+u_\eta\cdot\eta_y)$

$~~~~~~=u_{\xi\xi}\cdot\xi^2_y+u_{\xi}\cdot\xi_{yy}+2u_{\xi\eta}\cdot\xi_y\cdot\eta_y+u_\eta\cdot\eta_{yy}+u_{\eta\eta}\cdot\eta^2_y$

$~~~~~~=u_{\xi\xi}\cdot \dfrac{1}{1+y^2}-u_{\xi}\cdot \dfrac{y}{\left(1+y^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}}+2u_{\xi\eta}\cdot 0+u_\eta\cdot 0+u_{\eta\eta}\cdot 0$

$~~~~~~=\dfrac{u_{\xi\xi}}{1+y^2}-\dfrac{y~u_\xi}{\left(1+y^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}}$

Substituting these values in $(1)$ we have,

$(1+x^2)\left[\dfrac{u_{\eta\eta}}{1+x^2}-\dfrac{x~u_\eta}{\left(1+x^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}}\right]+(1+y^2)\left[\dfrac{u_{\xi\xi}}{1+y^2}-\dfrac{y~u_\xi}{\left(1+y^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}}\right]+x\left[\dfrac{u_\eta}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right]+y\left[\dfrac{u_\xi}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right]=0$

$\implies u_{\eta\eta} -\dfrac{x~u_\eta}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}+u_{\xi\xi}-\dfrac{y~u_\xi}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}+\dfrac{x~u_\eta}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}+\dfrac{y~u_\xi}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}=0$

$\implies u_{\eta\eta} +u_{\xi\xi}=0$

This is the required canonical form.